# Rearrangement of a Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know how to rearrange some types of formula on my homework.

The question I can't understand how to rearrange is making $x$ the subject in $y=(x+2)/(x-2)$.

Also, it asks my why $r$ cannot be made the subject in $V=\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3 + \pi r^2 h$. I can also not make $\pi$ the subject, which it asks me to do in part b. The third part asks if $r$ can be made the subject if $h$ equal to $r$, and to do so if it can.

I do not know how to do any of these.

Comment: There's a little bit of a learning curve, but see this [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on this site.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you call the *subject*?

Comment: @Bernard it means to describe $x$ as a function of $y$ in this case.

Comment: That's usually called  ‘finding the inverse of the function $f$’. I didn't know this terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question:

$y=\frac{x+2}{x-2}\Leftrightarrow y(x-2)=x+2\Leftrightarrow xy-2y=x+2$.

This should help you solve the equation for $x$.

Second question:

$r$ can be made the subject of the equation, but not without further formulas.

Third question:

If you replace $h$ with $r$, you get:

$V=\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3+\pi r^3=\frac{5}{3}\pi r^3$

Using cube roots, you can solve this equation for $r$ easily.